# How to create an empty page using sharepoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online

When i'm creating pages, using sharepoint online, i am getting page with uneditable left column and header. Is there any way to remove header and left column (`Display Quick Launch` is disabled, but logo and 'Site Contents' buttons is still on the page)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because its part of master page and not that actual page. You have two options

1. Customize your master page and remove left navigation and logo (This is not supported for OOB master pages and do this only if you are fine with same changes across the site)
2. If you want this only for current page, you can add CSS in CEWP and put display none.

   `#sideNavBox, #DeltaSiteLogo
   {
   display:none;
   }`

   `#contentBox
   {
   margin-left:20px;
   }`

Comment: Which one exactly master page should i edit? Minimal, oslo, seatle or v4?

Comment: Depends. If its a publishing site then seattle. V4 for team site. What you can do is, right click each master page (in SPD) . Wherever "Set as Default master page" is disabled (Greyed out), edit that maste page.

Comment: If i add css to masterpage it will affect all subsites, right?

Comment: I should allow to use Custom Scripts in my setting for using Content Editor, right?

Comment: Again depends, if its publishing site it will. For team site AFAIK it wont. You can try doing a small change and see if it affects. e.g Border color. Well, we are not putting any scripts, its just a CSS. Doesn't need any settings change.

Comment: What about my second question?) (about Content Editor)

Comment: Had answered in previous comment  :) "Well, we are not putting any scripts, its just a CSS. Doesn't need any settings "

Comment: Should i just add <style> in to page source? (btw SharePoint removing <style>) How should i add CSS using CEWP then?

Comment: Please refer this http://sharepoint.protiviti.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=169

Comment: It is works in editor (both ways, 2010 and 2013), but after saving sharepoint removing everything inside <style>

Comment: try putting CSS in text file and refer this in CEWP http://sharepointadam.com/2010/08/31/insert-javascript-into-a-content-editor-web-part-cewp/

Comment: If i'm trying to put any <link> using HTML Source it tells me (after saving) "Some of your markup was stripped out.  Try using the Embed command.". When i'm trying Embed command it tells me "This HTML cannot be inserted because you don't have access to add scriptable Web Parts in this site. Please contact your administrator if you think you should have rights to do so." :D

Comment: If it'll works (after allow to use Custom Scripts), i will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: I am alone on whole office 365. How is that even possible (don't have permissions to any function)?))

Comment: btw https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/300221 (it may help someone)

Comment: Finally it's works! But there is also header (#s4-titlerow) which have own styles '<div id="s4-titlerow" style="display:block;"'. Way to hide this?)

Comment: #s4-titlerow {display:none !important}